# Using notepad++ to search for & copy/select multiple lines

Tags: search, notepad++

I have a text file, which is huge. I wish to copy relevant parts out of it, however the parts i want span a total of 3 lines, for instance i can search for a string which is a server's IP, and manually copy and paste that line, and the 2 below it, what i wish to know, is there a way in which i can say to notepad++ for each match to my string, copy / mark / bookmark that line, and the 2 below it, so that i may mass copy and paste?

Sorry if this is the wrong board to have posted this, and thanks!

Comment: You can try recording a Macro, I'm not sure if it works perfectly, however I did something similar, and it worked

Comment: How would i make the macro know the copy / bookmark the next 2 lines relitive to the text string? As oposed to just bookmarking the same 3 lines.

Comment: Where do you want to paste the data?